# Failed to import file

Tags: graphdb

I have a RDF file that can be imported without any issues in another RDF store (Stardog) but keeps failing in GraphDB with this error :

15:58:18.900 [import-task-3-thread-1] ERROR c.o.f.i.MultipartFileImportRunnableTask - Could not import file
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.common.lang.service.ServiceRegistry.get(ServiceRegistry.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.Rio.createParser(Rio.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.Rio.createParser(Rio.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.util.RDFLoader.loadInputStreamOrReader(RDFLoader.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.util.RDFLoader.load(RDFLoader.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.base.AbstractRepositoryConnection.add(AbstractRepositoryConnection.java:329)
    at com.ontotext.trree.monitorRepository.MonitorRepositoryConnection.add(MonitorRepositoryConnection.java:159)
    at com.ontotext.trree.parallel.ParallelRDFLoader.add(ParallelRDFLoader.java:125)
    at com.ontotext.forest.impex.ParallelAwareImporter.lambda$add$3(ParallelAwareImporter.java:48)
    at com.ontotext.forest.impex.ParallelAwareImporter.wrapInBeginCommit(ParallelAwareImporter.java:66)
    at com.ontotext.forest.impex.ParallelAwareImporter.add(ParallelAwareImporter.java:48)
    at com.ontotext.forest.impex.MultipartFileImportRunnableTask.load(MultipartFileImportRunnableTask.java:38)
    at com.ontotext.forest.impex.ImportRunnableTask.run(ImportRunnableTask.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

This file can be found here : http://boetik-artistik.be/humidity_by_city.owls

All referenced ontologies are resolvable from my machine.

Thanks or your help.

Kind regards,
Johan,

Answer (score 2):

I have just tried this out myself on GraphDB 8.3.1. I got a similar error when I allowed GraphDB to auto detect the import format. However, when I selected the format as "RDF/XML", it imported without a problem.

The problem is with the file extension. It should be `.rdf` rather than `.owls`.